# $X \sim \mathsf{R}(0,1)$, $Y \sim \mathsf{R}(0,1)$. Set $U=(2-X)^3$ Calculate $f_U(u)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let X and Y be to independent random variables.
>
> $X \sim \mathsf{R}(0,1)$
>
> $Y \sim \mathsf{R}(0,1)$
>
> Set $U=(2-X)^3$
>
> Let $f(U)$ describe the probability density function for U.
>
> Calculate $f_U(u)$ and $F_U(u)$

I'm having some uncertainties whilst trying to calculate this.

My approach:
$P(U \leq u)$

$P((2-x)^3 \leq u)$

Isolate for x;

$x=(-u^{1/3}+2)$

Now this is where the first uncertainty kicks in. This minus value. Should I only look at numerical values and discard the minus in front of u since it's probabilities? The book's reveal nothing in these cases, and I've never tried a negative value before. Let's proceed though:

$\int_{0}^{(-u^{1/3}+2)}1 dx =(-u^{1/3}+2)$

Now the problem is that gives a CDF of:

$F_Y(Y)$ of:

$0$  if $u<1$

$(-u^{1/3}+2)$ if $1<u<8$

$1$   if $u>8$

Shouldn't it be $(u^{1/3}+2)$ if $1<u<8$?

Again, lets proceed:

To find the PDF of U:

$\frac{d}{du}(-u^{1/3}+2)=-\frac{1}{3·u^{2/3}} $

Resulting in:

$f_U(u)=-\frac{1}{3·u^{2/3}}$ if $u\in]1,8[$, 0 otherwise

The end result is not correct with the - in front of it. The correct result is:
$f_U(u)=\frac{1}{3·u^{2/3}}$ if $u\in]1,8[$, 0 otherwise

What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven´t solved $(2-x)^3\leq u$ correctly. You have to regard the inequality sign. Taking the cubic root:

$2-x\leq u^{1/3}$

$2-u^{1/3}\leq x$

Now we need $x\leq ... $. For this purpose we use the converse probability

$P(X\geq 2-u^{1/3})=F_U(u)=1-F_X( 2-u^{1/3})$.

Since $F_X(x)=x$ we get $F_U(u)=1-(2-u^{1/3})=u^{1/3}-1$

Differentiating w.r.t $u$ to obtain the the pdf

$\frac{dF_U(u)}{du}=\frac13\cdot u^{-2/3}$

Thus the pdf is

$$f_U(u)=\begin{cases} \frac13\cdot u^{-2/3}, 1\leq u\leq 8 \\ 0, \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Comment: I see. I forgot to "flip" the inequality when I multiplied with -1. Using my own method the correct result pops out when I use what I had put as an upper bound as a lower bound (since the inequality should be reversed). Thank you!

Comment: And besides this, thank you for a very clear, precise and understandable solution to the problem. I'll add your solution to my notes on the subject.

Comment: @Fauré You are welcome. Thanks for your kindly comment. Please also note the cdf. It is different from yours. Btw: Happy New Year.